# "Not a valid month" exception while updating date in Oracle database using NHibernate

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to update my date column in oracle using nhibernate but I keep getting
"Not a valid month" exception

```
   private static void InitializeSessionFactory()
    {
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure().Database(OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10.ShowSql().ConnectionString("Data Source="")
           ).Mappings(m =>
              m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Status>())

           .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

The variable that I used is a DateTime object and the column is date type.

Thanks you for your help

Comment: Can you post your code you used to configure your `SessionFactory`?

Comment: More important, the code being used for the update...

Comment: Look for implicit data type conversions. You are probably doing a useless to_date() or something like that somewhere in your SQL code.

Comment: I used session.update to update column into database

Comment: Can you also share the SQL generated?

Comment: UPDATE TEMP SET INIT_DATE = :p39, INIT_LOCATION = :p40 WHERE CASEID = :p41;, :p39 = 9/16/2005 12:00:00 AM[Type: DateTime (0)], :p40 = NULL [Type: String (0)], :p41 = 57 [Type: Int64 (0)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the table structure